# Allure listener throwing exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, maven-2, allure

I am getting below exception when run my code and it reach to allure listener class :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class test.loginTest cannot be cast to class base.DriverContext
```

I doubt that I am not flowing driver object through the framework the way I should but not getting any solution for this.

Below if my allure success method :

```
 public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("Method" + GetTestMethodName(iTestResult) + " Pass");
        Object testClass = iTestResult.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((DriverContext) testClass).Driver;
        if (driver instanceof WebDriver) {
            System.out.println("Screen captured for test case : " + GetTestMethodName(iTestResult) + ":Pass");
            saveScreenshotPNG(driver);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

check if LoginTest is extending the DriverContext if that is the case then you cant use a reference of derived class to store the object of a super class.

in your case you can take driver instance directly from the test itself instead of calling it via a super class.